# How to set interval for exactly for a month on partitoned table

Tags: oracle11g

I want auto create partition on my table month wise.

suppose i have created partition upto 28-feb-2018. after that i have set interval for a month using

alter table TBL_PARTITION set interval(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'));

when i am inseting march month data into my table, then march month partion auto created but partition created till 28-mar-2018.

My requirement is to create auto partition for exactly a month.In my example auto partition to be created till 31-march-218 as it is last day of month.

Please help me.

Comment: What was the original DDL for the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If  your table already has interval future you have to turn it off. If not go point 2

```
 alter table TBL_PARTITION set interval();
```

2) Add head partition when values are less than 1st of next month. In your case this partition will be only 2 day range

```
 alter table TBL_PARTITION add partition xxxxx values less than (TO_DATE('2018-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

3) Turn on interval partitioning

```
alter table TBL_PARTITION set interval(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'));
```